# How to use HTML in a webform component's title?

Tags: 8, theming, webforms

We have a checkbox which's title should have HTML (`<sup></sup>`) but its rendered as text rather than HTML.

How to use HTML in a webform component's title?

Answer (score 0):

At first, I misread your question and created [Issue #3036393: Allow basic HTML markup in element titles](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3036393).

Checkboxes do support HTML markup.

The below YAML…

```
checkbox:
  '#type': checkbox
  '#title': checkbox<sup>sup</sup>
checkboxes:
  '#type': checkboxes
  '#title': checkboxes
  '#options':
    one: one<sup>sup</sup>
    two: two<sup>sup</sup>
```

…renders via Bartik as…

[image]

If you can replicate and document this issue, [please create a ticket on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform?version=8.x).

Comment: i didnt mean the checkbox option, i meant the title of the whole element :) thanks!

Comment: so doesnt matter if a checkbox, radio, or whatever. your first thought was right, you cant put html in an elements title

Comment: Whole elements also support HTML in the title.